# How to get "public" share counts using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

When I get the number of shares using the FB Graph API Explorer (`{page-post-id}?fields=id,shares`) I get:

```json
{
  "id": "XXX_XXX",
  "shares": {
    "count": 79
  }
}
```

On the FB site, only shows "public" shares when we check:
[image]
(text at the bottom: "Some posts may not be displayed due to their privacy settings")

Is there any way to fetch this quantity of "public" shares using the Graph API?
Or some other way than checking manually on the FB page?

Comment: In theory, you could fetch the `sharedposts` edge, that should only return shares you have access to. Although in my tests, with the data that I have available, I only get an error saying, _"This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature."_ - I have the former, of course, but I guess some of the shared posts were made by other pages - so I would need PPCA feature approved for my app (which I don't have, and which you likely won't be granted either, because the allowed use cases for that are very restrictive.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I test `sharedposts` but it returns me: `{"date": []}` or only shares that I made with my app.

Comment: Looks like shares made by users will be hidden from your app, unless your app had permission to read the sharing user's posts (which makes sense.) So then there's really no way to get the info you're after, I think.

Comment: It seems to be as you say.